# sql comparing two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that gives me the score of an exam using the count function.  I need to perform the same functions to compare for example test1 with test2.

to find the first exam score I use the count function in and perform add some constraints in the where clause, and later grouping by username,

I need to compare this count with the second count which would need to be in a second select statement, however I cannot add a select statement in the having clause and i cannot do any operations on the count in the where clause.  Below is a basic idea of what I have right now

```
SELECT ur.uno, COUNT(*)*5 as test1
 FROM question q, 
      userresponse ur
WHERE q.eno = '1' 
  AND q.eno = ur.eno 
  AND q.qno = ur.qno 
  AND q.correctanswer = ur.response 
  AND test1 > (SELECT ur.uno, COUNT(*)*5
                 FROM question q1, 
                      userresponse ur1
                WHERE q1.eno = '3' 
                  AND q1.eno = ur1.eno 
                  AND q1.qno = ur1.qno 
                  AND q1.correctanswer = ur1.response
             GROUP BY ur.no)
GROUP BY ur.uno
```

This is my first approach however I get a test1 invalid identifier.  My other approach would be

```
select ur.uno, count(*)*5 as test1
from question q, userresponse ur
where q.eno = '1' and q.eno = ur.eno and q.qno = ur.qno and q.correctanswer = ur.response
group by ur.uno
having count(*)*5 > (select ur1.uno, count(*)*5 as test3
from question q1, userresponse ur1
where q1.eno = '3' and q1.eno = ur1.eno and q1.qno = ur.qno and q.correctanswer = ur.response
group by ur1.uno)
```

but I get a too many values errors, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ur.uno, 
       COUNT(case when q.eno='1' then 1 end)*5 as test1, 
       COUNT(case when q.eno='3' then 1 end)*5 as test3
 FROM question q, 
      userresponse ur
WHERE q.eno in ('1', '3')
  AND q.eno = ur.eno 
  AND q.qno = ur.qno 
  AND q.correctanswer = ur.response 
HAVING COUNT(case when q.eno='1' then 1 end) >
       COUNT(case when q.eno='3' then 1 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

@user541597 ; 
Hey remove  "ur.uno" from the inner query i think it will work..

Answer (score 0):

in first query

> where clause do not recognise alias so you may replace test1 .

in second query

you can change

```
select ur1.uno, count(*)*5 as test3
```

to

```
select count(*)*5 as test3
```

in second select statement to avoid too many values error.